# How bad is remote code execution in browser plugins?

Tags: firefox, browser, virus, firefox-extensions

There was a Firefox addon installed on my PC which is now blocked for executing remote code. Does a Firefox plugin have enough privileges to make change to the system (Windows) and "install" another backdoor etc. or are addons limited to the browser itself? In other words: Could this Vulnerability still be present on my PC or is it gone with the plugin being uninstalled?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, through a plugin your computer can be infected.

In fact Orcale de java is the worst culprit and most dangerous Java add-ons may be completely updated but still it would not matter, because the latest versions of Java still contain security vulnerabilities without patches.

Other browser add-ons, particularly Adobe Flash Player and PDF Reader add-ons, also have to regularly patch security vulnerabilities. Adobe has become better than Oracle to respond to these problems and patch their add-ons, but it is still common to hear that a new Flash vulnerability is being exploited.

Complements are juicy goals. Vulnerabilities in add-ins can be exploited in all different browsers with the add-in in all different operating systems. A Flash plug-in vulnerability could be used to exploit Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer running on Windows, Linux or Mac.

Comment: OK, thanks for your reply. I looked through the permissions and it didn't have any permissions which would allow it to access the system, i think. Probably gonna reset my password tho, as it had access to those.